# Passing js variables to django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I'm using jquery .submit() function to calculate two variables(f_amount and f_variables) but I don't know how to pass them to the next django view.

```
<form method="POST" action="/app/view">{% csrf_token %}                    
                    <select  id="fd" name="fd">
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select>

                <div id="demo2" class="demo">
                <ul>
                {% for f_type, fs in f.items %}
                    <li>
                        <a>{{ f_type }}</a>
                        <ul>
                            {% for f in fs %}
                                <li><a id="{{f.0}}">{{f.1}}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                </div>
                <input id="plan" type="submit" value="sched it!" class="btn primary" />
        </form>

<script>
$("form").submit(function() {
                var checked_ids = new Array();
                var f_amount = $("select option:selected").val();
                $("#demo2").jstree("get_checked",null,true).each 
                    (function (index,value) {
                        if (value.children[2].id) { 
                            checked_ids.push(value.children[2].id); 
                        }
                    });
                var f_ids = checked_ids.join(" ");

 });
</script>
```

Comment: The *next* Django view? Why not worry about the *current* Django view first.

Comment: They should be accessible via request.POST querydict object from your view. You can find more information on querydicts here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Comment: This is the QueryDict I get in the view loaded after the form submit, the variables f_amount and f_ids aren't in the dictionary:
<QueryDict: {u'check_1242': [u'1'], u'check_7599': [u'1'], u'check_9103': [u'1', u'1'], u'check_9293': [u'1'], u'check_7202': [u'1'], u'check_8142': [u'1'], ...}

Answer (score 1):

i could do it this way in Django 2.1

**x123.html**
First create a hidden input field like this in the 1st html file

```
<form id="scoresForm" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="scores" value=""/>
</form>
```

**views.py** then define your View in the views.py and do the POST data handling

```
def result(request, league_id, season_id, matchday):
    scores = request.POST.get("scores", None)
    if scores != None:
        scores = scores.replace("&quot;", "'")
    #scores = scores[1:-1]
    scores = json.loads(scores)
    context = {
        'league_id': league_id,
        'season_id': season_id,
        'matchday': matchday,
        'scores': scores,
    }
    return render(request, 'matchstatistics/result.html', context)
```

**x123.js** and lastly in your JS file which belongs to your 1st html template

```
    var resultUrl = currentUrl + "/result/" + league_id + "/" + season_id + "/" + matchday + "/";
    var scoresForm = document.forms['scoresForm'];
    scoresForm.action = resultUrl;
    scoresForm.elements["scores"].value = JSON.stringify(scores);
    document.getElementById("scoresForm").submit();
```

**y123.html** You are able to access the passed Array/Variable easily in your following view by calling f.e. {{ scores }} in your Django Template

Please feel free to optimize the code, especially the JSON-Object serialization and deserialization part, im new to Django/Python/JavaScript :)